# .net Core 3 Web API JWT unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization, jwt

I am beginner in the world of authentication and I am trying to implement a simple example to secure my api.

In my Login action I generate a JWT like:

```
var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThIsIsAKeyT03ncrypt!4lw4ysUs3AStr0ng1"));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "https://localhost:44392/",
                audience: "https://localhost:44392/",
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),  
               signingCredentials: creds);
```

My controller is tagged as follows:

```
[ApiController]    
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
```

and the StartUp class handles the authentication like:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

and:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                        {
                            ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:44392/",
                            ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44392/",
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ThIsIsAKeyT03ncrypt!4lw4ysUs3AStr0ng1")),
                            ValidateLifetime = true
                        };
                    });
```

The problem is that although I am using the same symmetric key, issuer and audience, when testing through postman, the result is always status 401.

[image]

Is there a setting/option I am missing? Any help would be welcome

Comment: Are you saying that you tried two approaches and one worked and the other didn't, or that neither worked? When you say "in the login action" do you mean a controller action method? Why are you generating a JWT there?

Comment: @TomW thanks for the comment. Well, there is one approach in my solution. When user is going to the Login and after identity server finds his credentials, I generate a JWT. This JWT needs to be handled in the Startup class. The solution on my problem is answered bellow (I missed some settings). Although,  why I shouldn't  generate in the Login action? Is there a better way for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding

```
 services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
```

in the StartUp class.